# SBTでCompileに依存するがTestの時には起動しないタスク

Tags: sbt

```
compile in Compile <<= (compile in Compile).dependsOn(myTask)
```

こう記述すると、コンパイルの前に指定したタスクが起動してくれるのですが、テストのとき(test:compile)にも動いてしまいます。
通常のCompileのみに依存させるには、どうしたら良いでしょうか？